# ¿Cómo hacer una gráfica con selección múltiple en Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access-2010

Hace unas unos días cree con *"Access 2010"* una tabla con un campo de opción múltiple **(32 opciones para ser exactos ya que se puede seleccionar mas de uno ejemplo: acción, terror, drama)**, utilizando las opciones de access **"Lookup Wizards "** y le di la opción de permitir múltiples valores, pero cuando deseo hacer una gráfica solo me utiliza el primer valor seleccionado del campo múltiple.

Así es como se hace la selección:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la gráfica con 7 usuarios que hicieron su selección (como verán solo me toma la primera selección):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna forma de separar cada opción para que se refleje en la gráfica?

Answer (score 2):

Encontré la solución de como dividir los campos múltiples, aparente mente al momento de hacer la query se debe incluir en el campo que contiene las opciones múltiples la sentencia ".Value", para que al momento de desplegar la información se divida.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esa forma el campo se dividirá por cada selección.